# This question was edited but not by me, though it shows that I edited it myself. I'm curious to know about it.

Tags: discussion

In this quesiton, [Sum this series $\frac{1}{1+1^2+1^4}+\frac{2}{1+2^2+2^4}+\ldots$ upto $n$ terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691109/sum-this-series-dfrac111214-dfrac212224-ldots-upto-n-term) , there were some typo error and some improvable latex available. I was suggested to do the edit by a senior member and when I tried to do that I found that it had already been edited. When I looked up the edit history, it showed that I edited it which I didn't. I am curious to know how this happened?

Comment: It looks as if you edited it to me. Perhaps a community team member or developer can tell more. I will attempt to get some attention.

Comment: @robjohn that is very kind of you...thank you...you are doing so much to satisfy my curiosity...thank you for that.

Comment: parallel universes often converge here at the meta.

Comment: If you explain in more detail what precisely you did when you "tried to do that", and what precisely you saw when you "found that it had already been edited", it would make it easier to come up with an explanation.

Comment: As I clicked on "edit", I saw the last edited version of the question in latex form and the preview being shown below that and the edit was titled as "Improved Latex". Just like that.